# Is their a way to ensure random recruits are always of a particular nationality and/or gender?

Tags: xcom-2

Can you set up your starting pool of recruits so that that are all the same nationality or gender, or only selected from countries in one region? It would be kind of fun if all your recruits were only from regions you have made contact with.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** to your first question, **no** to your second.

Filling your character pool with enough recruits to fill your entire starting roster and then selecting the "From Character Pool Only" option will cause the entirety of XCOM to be populated with these characters.  Simply pre-generate the characters to be of whatever nationality or gender you wish.

However, **this will only effect the start of your game**.  It is not possible to expand this concept to include "only regions you have made contact with" as the game progresses.  Furthermore, even **your starting location is random**, meaning that you will not be able to know what nationality to choose ahead of time.

Comment: As a slight addition to your question: The game does track where your recruits come from (region wise) and favors namelists (and nationalities) from that region. _Not 100% of recruits, but a large majority_. Which is at least closer to what OP is hoping to achieve. I am not sure if this was in X2 from the beginning, or whether it was patched in after your answer was posted.

Comment: @Flater Super interesting!